# Rewrite WebSocket messages via Nginx?

Tags: nginx, websocket, lua, openresty

Is it possible to rewrite the content of a websocket message proxied through Nginx?

For example, say I've sent a message with the contents `JSON.stringify({ auth: 'someIdKey' })`. On Nginx, I would to substitute the value of `someIdKey` to `someJwt`, then forward it to the proxied upstream resource. I'd also want to do the reverse translation when the upstream resource sends out messages back to the client.

I know how to do this (and am doing this) for HTTP requests, rewriting custom headers to do an on-the-fly translation, but I'm not sure how to approach carrying over the pattern to websocket communication.

I'm using [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/) as my Nginx distribution and am passably-ok at Lua scripting.

Would appreciate any ideas/help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-websocket module.

It has both server and client side non-blocking API. So you can program anything you want.

Comment: It is non-blocking for nginx, but not for the script itself. If you stuck in recv_frame(), then when downstream sends you data it will be stuck too (as far as api imposes this little detail).

Comment: @user3125367 you may use light thread and implement 2 event loops